# How to pass command-line keyword argument to class variable in scrapyd?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I am working on a scrapy project. I want to know how to pass an argument from a scrapyd api-call to a spider class.

I want to pass the keyword argument (file_path='C:\') to the dictionary variable in my spider class.

I try the following two methods but they didn't work.

Method 1:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'MySpider'

    custom_settings = { 'FEED_URI': self.file_path }
```

Method 2:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'MySpider'

    def __init__(self, file_path ='', **kwargs):
        custom_settings = {
            'FEED_URI' :  file_path + '.json'
        }
        super(MySpider,self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

I have read the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments). I tried my best to follow the document but I didnt quite get the idea.

Comment: The "self" in the first method is allowed. I dont know why but if I add self.file_path inside a def it is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following simple method, I know that it works for setting `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED` and `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` for example, it might work for `FEED_URI` as well:

```
curl localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=MySpider -d spider=MySpider -d setting=FEED_URI=whatever
```

Check the last schedule.json-example from [the official scrapyd-documentation](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule-json) where the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` is set to 2.

Other then that there are multiple issues that try to achieve the exact same thing but without scrapyd involved, maybe they are helpful for you:
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3900
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2392

By the way: with Scrapy 2.1.0 `FEED_URI` is now marked as [deprecated](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#deprecations).

Answer (score 0):

To access command line arguments in python, you need to enumerate over `sys.argv`

For example:

```
import sys
for arg in sys.argv:
    print(arg)
```

Then run the script from cli with an argument
`python main.py name=hello`

The output will be each argument given via the cli, the first arg being script name, each argument in this list will be an String,

To make avoid manually parsing the arguments you can use the python package [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: I understand what you mean. But how about I pass the argument in commend line. Actually I am using scrapyd. I pass the argument like following:

Comment: curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=MySpider-d spider=MySpider-d file_path=ABC

Comment: I understand what you suggest. But what normally apply on kwargs is not quite the same when applying to scrapy here. Basically the scrapy is the main class.  And the scrapy library has already has define way to pass the argument from command line to Myspider. Like the following document shown. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not clear what's the issue you're facing. If you could update your question to be more clear about the exact issue it would be better, either way scrappy is a python framework so the above should still work,. But as it's not clear I'm unable to guide you further